# Spring Specifications with Inheritance

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, specifications

How can I get a typecast into "Specification" "toPredicate" method?

Ex:

```
@Entity
public class Empresa{...}

@Entity
public class Cliente extends Empresa{ 
    private Integer cod;
    ...
}
@Entity
public class Vinculo{
    private Empresa emp1;
    private Empresa emp2;
}


public static Specification<Vinculo> serieEq(final Integer cod) {
    return new Specification<Vinculo>() {
    @Override
        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Vinculo> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
            return cb.equal(root.join("emp2").get("cod"), cod);
    };
}
```

Note that "cod" is only present in Cliente.

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the as() API.  This will work on some JPA providers.

Comment: It works with EclipseLink, but not with Hibernate. Here is a more detailled answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6427126/polymorphic-criteriaquery-without-inverse-relationship